A roller mechanism with bearings at both end
A roller mechanism that can fit in variety diameter of shaft (15, 20, 25 & 30 mm), and then can be take it off easily.

Your question isn't a question. Consider to edit it to conform with StackExchange guidelines.

A 30 mm shaft's bearing rolls fine on a 15 mm shaft. Doesn't constrain tightly to the shaft without something else (such as additional 30mm offset bearings or some clamp). What do you need it to do?

you need to describe what you are looking for.  "Roller mechanism" could mean anything.  What does "fit in a shaft" mean?  Write a specification people can understand please.

@Abel the OP said in a shaft, not on a shaft
